# apache-контейнер за проксирующим nginx-контейнером

Tags: apache, nginx, docker, docker-compose, owncloud

Есть контейнер [owncloud](https://hub.docker.com/_/owncloud/). Внутри него крутится Apache. Пробрасываю порты `9000:80`

Есть другой контейнер с nginx. Я хочу, чтобы nginx проксировал запросы к контейнеру с apache. Т.е. чтобы по локейшну `/owncloud` (`https://domain.com/owncloud`) был доступен первый контейнер.
Часть конфигурации docker-compose:

```
  owncloud:
    image: owncloud:8.1
    container_name: owncloud
    ports:
      - 9000:80
```

Часть конфигурации nginx:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain.com;

  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www/letsencrypt;
  }

  location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl_certificate certs/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key certs/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

  server_name domain.com;

  root /var/www/html;

...
...
...

  location  /owncloud {
    proxy_pass http://domain.com:9000/;
    }
}
```

Но полноценно запросы не обрабатываются. nginx проксирует запрос к apache, но в итоге ищет все нужные файлы у себя в контейнере (т.е в `root`-директории). Немного лога:

```
owncloud       | 172.19.0.1 - - [12/Jul/2017:15:45:17 +0000] "GET /owncloud/index.php HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "https://domain.com/owncloud/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
nginx          | 46.28.229.85 - - [12/Jul/2017:15:45:17 +0000] "GET /owncloud/index.php HTTP/1.1" 400 425 "https://domain.com/owncloud/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0" "-"
nginx          | 46.28.229.85 - - [12/Jul/2017:15:45:26 +0000] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0" "-"
nginx          | 2017/07/12 15:45:26 [error] 7#7: *1 open() "/var/www/html/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 46.28.229.74, server: domain.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
```

Я так понимаю, что необходимо добавить правильные параметры для прокси в конфиг nginx? Но я потратил полдня, перепробовав многие, и в итоге ничего не заработало. Как сделать так, чтобы nginx проксировал все запросы к apache и не умничал? :)

P.S. Сейчас я подумал о том, что можно пробросить данные из owncloud-контейнера в nginx-контейнер, но я думаю, что проблема должно как-то по-другому решаться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я переделал подход в целом:

servers as locations -> servers as subdomains

Оказалось, так намного проще настраивать сервисы. Видимо, из-за неопытности я выбрал неправильный подход вначале. Теперь же с применением поддоменов в конфигурации nginx всё отлично проксируется с полпинка.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В [документации nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) приведён такой пример:

```
location = / {
    [ конфигурация А ]
}

location / {
    [ конфигурация Б ]
}

location /documents/ {
    [ конфигурация В ]
}

location ^~ /images/ {
    [ конфигурация Г ]
}

location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ {
    [ конфигурация Д ]
}
```

Запрос `/` будет соответствовать конфигурации А, запрос `/index.html` - конфигурации Б, запрос `/documents/document.html` - конфигурации В, запрос `/images/1.gif` - конфигурации Г, а запрос `/documents/1.jpg` - конфигурации Д

У вас же в блоке `location /owncloud { ... }` нужно поставить ещё один слэш, как в документации про конфигурацию В:

```
location /owncloud/ {
    proxy_pass http://domain.com:9000/;
}
```

И тогда запросы вида `/owncloud/index.php` пойдут в apache

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но и со слешем, конечно же, пробовал, и должным образом запросы не обрабатывались (либо я делал что-то не так). Я решил проблему, переделав подход к архитектуре, перейдя от location к subdomains. Это более цивилизованный подход, мне кажется. :)